# Is it possible to close a kafka streams window before its retention period?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

First of all, I must say that I'm new to Kafka and streaming, but I'll try to explain the problem the best I can.

My team is currently developing and application to process data using Kafka Streams. We're using windowing to perform aggregation operations and we need to emit the results only when the window is closed.

Now here's the problem itself: our window retention period is of three days (yes, that is correct). We must keep the window open for this long period of time in case any record arrives late, but the normal course of the operations is that all the records arrive on time and we're able to identify when one batch is complete so, form most of the time, the windows don't need to stay open for so long.

So my question is: knowing that the last record of a batch has already arrived before the 3-day window retention period, is it possible to close the window and emit the aggregation results?

Comment: That is not possible. Maybe you could build a custom solution using the Processor API.

Comment: Thank you @MatthiasJ.Sax , I'll try to do that.